How to determine the LS category of branched covers?
Define the (normalized) Lusternik-Schnirelmann (LS) category of a space $X$, denoted $\mathsf{cat}(X)$ to be the least integer $n$ such that $X$ can be covered by $n+1$ number of open sets $U_i$ each of which is included null-homotopically in $X$. The sets $U_i$ can also be replaced by closed sets, and if $X$ is a metric ANR, then the sets $U_i$ can be arbitrary subsets of $X$. There are other equivalent formulations of $\mathsf{cat}(X)$ due to Ganea (and Schwarz) and Whitehead.
Let $X$ and $Y$ be metric ANRs. It is well known that if $p:X \to Y$ is a covering map, then $\mathsf{cat}(X) \le \mathsf{cat}(Y)$. I want to know if such an inequality holds in the case of branched coverings as well (see Wikipedia). More precisely, if $\widetilde{p}:X \to Y$ is a branched cover, is there a relation between $\mathsf{cat}(X)$ and $\mathsf{cat}(Y)$? One can additionally assume that $Y$ is compact and the branching locus of $\widetilde{p}$ is finite.

There's no relation, because every PL manifold is a branched covering of a sphere; see J. W. Alexander, Note on Riemann spaces, 1920, Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 26.

Thank you for this observation. Well, if the branched cover space $X$ is fixed as a "nice" manifold, then can one put an upper bound on $\mathsf{cat}(Y)$ using $\mathsf{cat}(X)$ somehow? In the case when $Y$ is a sphere, certainly $\mathsf{cat}(Y) \le \mathsf{cat}(X)$ holds, but is there some better upper bound that one can obtain for arbitrary compact metric $Y$? (such an estimate is possible if $X$ is the total space of a fiber bundle over $Y$).

Well, you obviously cannot restrict anything in general. because there are $K(G, 1)$ manifolds of maximal cup length: for example, a torus, which has Euclidean space as an unbrached cover.

One can cook up examples with finite degree branched coverings of similar nature, approximating $K(\Bbb Z/ p \Bbb Z ^k, 1)$.
